# Will statically linked executables work across OSX machines

Tags: macos, linker, static-linking

Will statically-linked executables compiled under OS X work when simply copied to another OS X machine?

Answer (score 4):

No. To quote Apple's article "[Statically linked binaries on Mac OS X](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1118/_index.html)":

> Apple does not support statically linked binaries on Mac OS X. A statically linked binary assumes binary compatibility at the kernel system call interface, and we do not make any guarantees on that front.

Indeed, attempting to build a static executable using the Xcode toolchain will yield an error:

```
sh% cc -static example.c -o example
ld: library not found for -lcrt0.o
```

Comment: Thanks. What are best practices of distributing OSX binaries? How should I pass my executables to others so they can run them?

Comment: For desktop applications, or standalone binaries?

Comment: Link dynamically against any libraries that are provided with the OS. For libraries that are not standard, you will need to either link these in statically (*not* the same as statically linking the entire binary!), or include dynamic libraries with the executable. Linking relative to `@rpath` may be helpful in the latter case.